# The instance of entity type 'Stage' cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have code, when i try add stage to context i get exception:

> The instance of entity type 'Stage' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the same key value for {'PartId', 'StorageId'}
> is already being tracked.

but i got record by Primary Keys.

```
var oldRecord = await context
                    .Stage
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.StorageId == storageId && x.PartId == part.Partid)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

if (oldRecord == null)
{
    var newRecord = new Stage
    {
        StorageId = storageId,
        PartId = part.Partid,
        Number = part.AmountIn,
    };
    context.Stage.Add(newRecord);
}
else
{
    oldRecord.Number += part.AmountIn;
    context.Stage.Update(oldRecord);
}
```

Comment: Your tables primary key consists of  `{'PartId', 'StorageId'}` properties. So probably `newRecord` has same values with the existing entity.

Comment: before add new record i try get old record, with the same fields.

Comment: @RussianPupokPupok If the first `Stage` instance with this primary key has been added to the context but `SaveChanges()` has not yet been called it will not be returned by your `FirstOrDefault()` check and then this exception occurs.